# EF migrations - call custom sql that is included into separate folder

Tags: entity-framework, migration

For now we have used only initial migration but now our team is planning to use EF update migrations.

My question is about custom SQL:

- I see that I can add custom SQL into migration
- I see I can add it using SQL ("Update bla bla")

Instead I would like to add all custom SQL into a separate folder. How to call custom SQL  that is included in separate folders?

P.S. We use EF 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature will be available in version 6.1.2, currently available as beta:

SqlFile and SqlResource methods on DbMigration allow you to run a SQL script stored as a file or embedded resource.

Currently you can use:

```
var sqlFile = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, 
    @"Migrations\Custom.sql"); 
Sql(File.ReadAllText(sqlFile));
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/09/18/ef6-1-2-beta-1-available.aspx

https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/561

Comment: And what if we don't want to change to beta version right now? What other method you suggest?

Comment: Great answer - stating the obvious, but you need to change your sql file properties from "None" to "Copy always"

Comment: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory will return ...bin\Debug folder that is not where Migrations folder is.